# PowerShell script generates lots of warnings in Windows Event Log

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-event-log, powershell-v4.0

I have a - rather complex - PowerShell script running on a Windows Server 2008 R2. When executing the script in the ISE or also in the console, everything runs fine. No errors or anything else that would stand out.

However, in the Windows Event viewer lots of Warnings are being generated without any specific reason that I can see.

```
Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational

Source: PowerShell (Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell)

Event ID: 4100

Task Category: Executing Pipeline

    Error Message = System error.
    Context:
    Severity = Warning
    Host Name = Windows PowerShell ISE Host
    Host Version = 4.0
    Host ID = cec010f3-ea0f-44b0-8d2e-449a6c1eb3e6
    Engine Version = 4.0
    Runspace ID = b2e8d39c-4fa1-4a3f-b33e-b42f8b552c3d
    Pipeline ID = 17
    Command Name = 
    Command Type = 
    Script Name = 
    Command Path = 
    Sequence Number = 92
    User = [the executing user]
    Shell ID = Microsoft.PowerShell


    User Data:
```

Google did not reveal anything. Does anyone have an idea what this could mean? As I said, there are hundrets of those entries. Let me know if I should post anything more.

Thanks a lot!

### edit: As requested the entire event XML

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell" Guid="{A0C1853B-5C40-4B15-8766-3CF1C58F985A}" /> 
<EventID>4100</EventID> 
<Version>1</Version> 
<Level>3</Level> 
<Task>106</Task> 
<Opcode>19</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x0</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-16T14:06:07.066866300Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>1994921</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation ActivityID="{01EC0C48-F800-0001-6B28-234CAE5DD001}" /> 
<Execution ProcessID="6528" ThreadID="5376" /> 
<Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational</Channel> 
<Computer>[host]</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1482476501-1450960922-725345543-2410959" /> 
</System>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextInfo">Severity = Warning Host Name = Windows PowerShell ISE Host Host Version = 4.0 Host ID = cec010f3-ea0f-44b0-8d2e-449a6c1eb3e6 Engine Version = 4.0 Runspace ID = b2e8d39c-4fa1-4a3f-b33e-b42f8b552c3d Pipeline ID = 36 Command Name = Command Type = Script Name = Command Path = Sequence Number = 7665 User = [user name] Shell ID = Microsoft.PowerShell</Data> 
  <Data Name="UserData" /> 
  <Data Name="Payload">Error Message = System error.</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

### Added `PS D:\Autonomy\cd_provisioning_client> ($PsVersionTable)`

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209                                                                                                                                                                                        
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

### `powershell_ise.exe.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
</startup> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Has the account that the script is running under all permissions necessary to execute and access everything in the script?

Comment: yes. See the answers and comments below for the actual reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When executing the script in the ISE or also in the console,
>   everything runs fine. No errors or anything else that would stand out.

Runs fine doesn't means there is no errors encountered. Your script probably just ignores them, using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` parameter with cmdlets. Example:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ZZZ:\
```

This will generate so called [terminating error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878319.aspx) and will stop the current pipeline, but because the [ErrorActionPreference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx) variable is by default set to `Continue`, the script itself will continue execution. And, as you can see, PowerShell host will log this error to the Event Log.

If you'd like to debug your script and find what error causes this log record, set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop` at the beginning of your script and run it. The first encountered error will stop the script execution and then you can view the error details like this `$Error[0]`.

**UPDATE:** I'm at loss, since everything we've tried didn't led to substantial result:

- `$Error` variable is empty
- `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` didn't catch anything
- `$PsVersionTable` and `powershell_ise.config` are looking fine to me

It's definitely something strange going on here and I don't believe that those empty fields are normal:

```
Command Name = 
Command Type = 
Script Name = 
Command Path =
```

While I still have some ideas to try, they require more thorough research:

- Check your script for any non-PowerShell objects\method (third-party assemblies, COM-Objects, etc...) and try to comment them out.
- Try monitoring PowerShell process with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Good luck!

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, this could make sense. I will give this a try later and come back.

Comment: I just tried that now. Set it to `Stop` at the beginning of the script. But the script does not terminate at any point. It stil produces windows events, though. Any further idea?

Comment: How peculiar! :). Is there anything in the `$Error` variable after script execution? Btw, could you post the entire XML of the event, there may be some details hidden there.

Comment: no, `$Error` is empty. I added the XML above.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I can't find any hidden gems in your XML. But here is another idea: how about setting `Set-StrictMode -Latest` at the beginning? Maybe it has something to do with access to the uninitialized variables or references to non-existent properties of an object.

Comment: How do you mean? `Set-StrictMode -Latest` does not exist, i.e. fails if I try it. There is `Set-StrcitMode -Version` do you mean this? If so, which version? :) thx!

Comment: My bad, that should be `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`.

Comment: this works, but still no change :(

Comment: Hmm, let's look at your PowerShell version table (`$PsVersionTable`) and config files (`powershell_ise.config`, `powershell.exe.config` in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`).

Comment: sure, see above.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see anything suspicious there. I've updated my answer with the list of things we tried to keep others from sifting through comments, but I'm out of ideas for now. Good luck and keep me posted if you happen to figure this out.

Comment: Argh, by debugging the entire script step by step I finally found the problematic line...

`$changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values | select -Index 0`
The last part `| select -Index 0` is the problem. The variable can consist of one or more parts. If it is only one part and therefore of type string, the last part fails.

That being said, do you have any idea why it did not stop on this error?

Comment: Well, nevermind, I'll put this one into a new question. You have been really helpful nevertheless. If there comes no better answer, I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you finally nailed it. If you'll post a new question, I'll look at it. To speed up things, please include object types of `$changeRecord.newAttrs[0]` and the last `$_[0]` in the pipeline:  `$changeRecord.newAttrs[0].GetType()` and `$_[0].GetType()`. ``$changeRecord.newAttrs[0]` | Export-Clixml` or even `$changeRecord | Export-Clixml` would be even better, depending on your object and resulting XML size.